# Problems with Compose BasicTextField:

Tags: android, kotlin, android-view, android-jetpack-compose

Now I have a custom Compose input box. BasicTextField, but I can’t center the input font anyway. I can only offset in the x direction through the offset property of the Box.

The reason for customizing the input box is because I need a fixed height input box and font size. But the text field cannot be input when the height is not enough.

Please help me, I prefer to use TextField to write input boxes with a fixed height. But no suitable solution was found on the site.

Here is my custom code:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun InputEditText(
    value: String,
    modifier: Modifier,
    onValueChange: (String) -> Unit,
    contentTextStyle: TextStyle,
    hintTextStyle: TextStyle,
    placeHolderString: String = "",
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    readOnly: Boolean = false,
    singleLine: Boolean = false,
    maxLines: Int = Int.MAX_VALUE,
    offsetDp: Dp = 10.dp,
    keyboardOptions: KeyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default,
    keyboardActions: KeyboardActions = KeyboardActions.Default,
    cursorColor: Color = Color.Black,
) {
    BasicTextField(
        value = value,
        onValueChange = onValueChange,
        modifier = modifier,
        textStyle = contentTextStyle,
        decorationBox = {innerTextField ->
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .offset(x = offsetDp),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.CenterStart,
            ) {
                if (value.isEmpty()) {
                    Text(
                        text = placeHolderString,
                        color = hintTextStyle.color,
                        fontSize = hintTextStyle.fontSize
                    )
                }

                innerTextField()

            }
        },
        enabled = enabled,
        readOnly = readOnly,
        singleLine = singleLine,
        maxLines = maxLines,
        keyboardOptions = keyboardOptions,
        keyboardActions = keyboardActions,
        cursorBrush = SolidColor(cursorColor)
    )
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
BasicTextField(
    textStyle = LocalTextStyle.current.copy(textAlign = TextAlign.Center),
    decorationBox = {innerTextField ->
        Box(
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center 
        ) {
            if (text.isEmpty()) {
                Text(
                    text = "placeHolder",
                )
            }
            innerTextField()
        }
    }
)
```

[image]